# treemacs does not work with gnu Emacs 27.1

Tags: treemacs

Can someone tell me if treemacs works with gnu-emacs 27.1.  When I

> M-x treemacs

I've got

> Error in post-command-hook (treemacs-post-command): (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)